# Trying to get data from Lumen Application with Angular 2 Http

Tags: angular, lumen

I am learning Angular 2, and I want to build application which has backend in Lumen Framework and Frontend in Angular 2.

I already created method to get the data from database and I am returning it in this way

```
return response()->json(['code' => 200, 'characters' => $characters])->header('content-type', 'application/json')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

and in angular 2 app I am trying to get this data by this code

```
this.http.get(this.url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Character[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

But i get back an empty array, I am shoor that the url to getting back data is ok, and also that data exists.

I tried to return something like return->response('test') and I see that string test exists.

Comment: try it without the `.data` ie. `response.json()` instead of `response.jsons().data`

Comment: I tried it it does not work

Comment: @Tomek Have you checked your network tab, how that response looks like?

Comment: yes of course, it looks something like this

{"code":200,"characters":[{"id":1,"name":"tomek","lead":"something about tomek","created_at":"2017-03-06 17:34:45","updated_at":"2017-03-06 17:34:45"},{"id":2,"name":"test2","lead":"test21","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "code":200,
  "characters":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"tomek",
      "lead":"som‌​ething about tomek",
      "created_at":"2017-03-06 17:34:45",
      "updated_at":"2017-03-06 17:34:45"
    }
  ]
}
```

and when you are trying to extract:

```
response.json().data
```

..there is no such property like `data`. If you want to extract your array, you need to use

```
response.json().characters
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Well it is working, thanks for help, I did not see the result before because of the promise, i was not waiting long enough. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome, please consider accepting the answer since it helped you. You can do that by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer :) Moreover, happy coding! :)

Comment: yeah great idea.